# Chrome incognito does not answer, can I get a list of the tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I have four incognito windows open, all of them aren't answering and I'd like a list of the tabs. Is that possible? Chrome is using around 30% of CPU, but less than 80 MB of RAM. Windows 10, latest stable Chrome.